# Can't connect to remote MySQL, even after tweaking my.conf bind-address

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, remote-access

I'm running `MySQL 5.5` under `Ubuntu 13` on an `Amazon EC2` instance.

I can't connect to MySQL remotely.  In my.conf, I changed bind-address from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`, which supposedly allows anyone to connect.  And Ubuntu's default iptables have no rules, allowing any port.

No dice.  An attempt to connect fails with, `"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ecblah4-80-blah131.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (4)"`

And now when I change my.conf's bind-address back to 127.0.0.1 and try to restart MySQL, the restart fails with "`InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11"`.  I've seen other references to that one but no solution other than rebooting.

Anybody have any insight here?  Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you using RDS, where such DBA rubbish is sorted for you?

Comment: Are you running the Mysql service as root? Are there any other instances running?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I was not running MySQL as root, and there should have been no other instances running because I rebooted (to temporarily solve the "unable to lock" error).